# SavedStateHandle doesn't contain navigation arguments

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle, koin

I'm trying to inject `SavedStateHandle`. I am using Koin, Jetpack Compose and Navigation.
I've managed to make it work, but I think it's not the right instance (I don't get my values).

This is what I do so far:

Setting the argument:

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addDetails(
    navController: NavHostController,
    root: Screen
) {
    composable(route = LeafScreen.Details.createRoute(root),
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("showId") { type = NavType.LongType }
        )) {
        DetailsScreen(navigateUp = navController::navigateUp)
    }
}
```

Defining my ViewModel:

```
internal class DetailsViewModel(
    val handle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val getMovieDetailsUseCase: GetMovieDetailsUseCase
) : ViewModel()
```

Defining my composable:

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    navigateUp: () -> Unit
) {
    DetailsScreen(
        viewModel = getStateViewModel(),
        navigateUp = navigateUp,
    )
}
```

And my modules:

```
val uiDetailsModules = module {
    viewModelOf(::DetailsViewModel)
}
```

It runs but `showId` from `val showId = handle.get<Long>("showId")` is null.

Comment: `getStateViewModel` returns module scoped view model, use `getViewModel` instead - this view model is route scoped and so `SavedStateHandle` should work

Comment: That won't work. Now I get an error: `Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle'. Check your definitions!`

Comment: not sure what's `viewModelOf`, it should be `viewModel { (handle: SavedStateHandle) -> DetailsViewModel(handle, get()) }`

Comment: Now I get a new error `org.koin.core.error.NoParameterFoundException: Can't get injected parameter #0 from DefinitionParameters[] for type 'androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle'`

Comment: https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/#state-handle-injection

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work...

Comment: Please edit your question with `createRoute` used in `LeafScreen.Details.createRoute(root)` and with how you call `navigate` with your long argument

Comment: @PhilDukhov sorry for the delayed response. [Here](https://pastebin.com/xQEsNx4z) is my code

Comment: I have the same problem, but what I found is that value is actually stored in SavedStateHandle, the only problem is it's always String, no matter what type was set in `navArgument("showId") { type = NavType.LongType }`
For now I am using workaround like `val showId = handle.get<String>("showId").toLong()`. If you have the same situation, then it can be a bug with compose navigation.

Comment: This should be solved in newer versions of the library. Regarding your issue, I don't really know how it works. As far as I remember, in my case it was ok.